# Proof $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have read the [following proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product/Proof_2) , in here:

[image]

Why can we go from the first line to the second one?

why $Det(E^k)\cdot Det(E^m)=Det(E^k\cdot E^m)$?

is it because $\det(E^k)\in \mathbb{F}$ for all $k$?

Comment: Have you read the three lines above, starting by "But for any matrix $\mathbf{D}$"?

Comment: The idea of the proof is to show that elementary matrices satisfy the multiplicative property for each case of elementary matrices, and then to use that fact to prove it generally.

Comment: Who exactly is $\Bbb F$?

Comment: You can go from the first line to the second because they've already established that the multiplicative property holds for elementary matrices.

Comment: @AlexM. a field In my case $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @gbox what do you mean by $\det(E^k) = \Bbb F$? Do you actually mean $\det(E^k) \in \Bbb F$?

Comment: fixed the field issue, sorry

Comment: @gbox what definition of the determinant do you use?

Comment: @thkim1011 why does elementary matrices satisfy the multiplicative property?

Comment: @gbox Have you read [this article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant)? It links to the three proofs for how elementary matrices change the determinant of a matrix after multiplication.

Comment: @eigenchris yes, the are changing the determinate by scalar, that is why it is true?

Comment: @gbox The three proofs are linked under the "proof" section.

Comment: @eigenchris yes how row operation change the determinant

Comment: @gbox I don't know what else to tell you... the proof for the question you are asking is linked right in the article I gave you...

Comment: @eigenchris my question is why $Det(E^k)\cdot Det(E^m)=Det(E^k\cdot E^m)$

Comment: @gbox Have you read [these](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiple_of_Row_Added_to_Row_of_Determinant) [three](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_with_Rows_Transposed) [articles](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_with_Row_Multiplied_by_Constant)? What is it about them you don't understand?

Comment: @eigenchris yes, maybe it is trivial from those three articles, but I am trying to understand why $Det(E^k)\cdot Det(E^m)=Det(E^k\cdot E^m)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property $\det(E^iE^j) = \det(E^i)\det(E^j)$ doesn't just hold for two elementary matrices $E^i,E^j$, it holds for any elementary matrix $E$ and any matrix $A$:

$$\det(EA) = \det(E)\det(A)$$

---

Proof:

There are three types of elementary matrices:

- row-scaling
- row-swapping
- row-adding

If I have some matrix $A$ with determinant $\det(A)$, and I multiply $A$ by some elementary matrix $E$ to get $EA$, then...

- if $E$ is a row-scaling matrix which scales a row of $A$ by a constant $c$, we can easily see that $\det(E) =c$ since $E$ is the identity matrix, but with one diagonal element changed to $c$. We can also show that $\det(EA) = c\det(A) = \det(E)\det(A)$ [[proof]](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_with_Row_Multiplied_by_Constant)
- if $E$ is a row-swapping matrix, then $det(E) = -1$ since it is simply the identity matrix with two rows swapped. We can show that $\det(EA) = -\det(A) = \det(E)\det(A)$ [[proof]](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_with_Rows_Transposed)
- if $E$ is a row-adding matrix which adds two rows of $A$ together, with one of the rows scaled by a constant $k$, then $\det(E) = 1$ since it is simply the identity matrix with one non-zero off-diagonal element $k$. We can also show that $\det(EA) = \det(A) = \det(E)\det(A)$ [[proof]](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiple_of_Row_Added_to_Row_of_Determinant)

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is a multiplicative function on $M_n(R)$, where $R$ is the base (commutative) ring:
$$\det(AB)=\det A\cdot\det B$$
for *any* $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $R$, and not only when one is an elementary matrix.

Comment: Thanks, but I have yet learned about rings

Comment: Replace  ring by field, or even $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$: I wanted to point this is a very *general* property.