# Proof for $\det(EA) = \det(E)\det(A)$ where E is an elementary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is there a easy proof for $\det(EA)=\det(E)\det(A)$, where E is an elementary matrix? Determinant here is defined through cofactor expansion.

I checked [Proof $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404015/proof-detab-deta-detb) and one answer there linked a wiki - https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_with_Row_Multiplied_by_Constant

In proof 1 section of the link, they put, [image]
However, when I go to "Determinant of Matrix Product" - https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product and try to see its proof, they put[image]
and I don't see any proof for $\det(EA) = \det(E)\det(A)$, so it circles back to the question - [Proof $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404015/proof-detab-deta-detb).
I haven't learned about permutations, so I have trouble understanding the proof 1 section of the wiki link. I would be glad if you show me a proof for $\det(EA)=\det(E)\det(A)$ without permutations.

My previous question was [Is there any easy way to prove $\det(EA) = \det(E)\det(A)?$, where $E$ is an elementary matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136681/is-there-any-easy-way-to-prove-detea-dete-deta-where-e-is-an-ele). But I found that it was not a duplicated question-please check the comments-so I am asking the question again.

I checked [Proof of determinants for matrices of any order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254620), [Proof $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1404015), and [How to show that $\det(AB) =\det(A) \det(B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb), but they don't explain what I want to know.

Comment: I've seen this proof done by cases. There are only so many different types of elementary matrices, and there are nice formulas for the entries of $ED$ in terms of the entries of $D$. I think the proof works out most nicely when using the sum over permutations definition of the determinant.

Comment: If you haven't learned about permutations, what *definition* of the determinant are you using?

Comment: @HansLundmark I asked an almost identical question last time momo asked this, so I don't know why that wasn't in the body of the question this time around... In any case, OP said they defined the determinant through cofactor expansion.